# Debian network configuration causes browsers to fail downloading

Tags: debian, networking, networkmanager

I have just recently installed debian on my PC. I installed gnome, which currently uses NetworkManager to manage my networking. My `/etc/network/interfaces` is empty except for `source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*`.

This issue affects both chromium and firefox, manifesting as "Download failed" messages. It manages to download these files bit by bit, but constantly fails in the process. Wget was able to download the same file without issues. When investigating this error, I saw that the download seems to fail on this messsage in chromium:

```
[9559:9602:0912/141853.151714:VERBOSE1:bus.cc(703)] Requested to remove an unknown filter function: 1 with associated data: 0x7f06500472e0
[9559:9602:0912/141853.151737:VERBOSE1:bus.cc(703)] Requested to remove an unknown filter function: 1 with associated data: 0x7f0650046d00
```

To me, this seems like an issue with some kind of configuration, but I'm clueless as to where that would be.

Edit: After disabling and stopping NetworkManager and using debians builtin interfaces system, the problem was resolved. However, I would like to use NetworkManager (because of the integration with gnome).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing to "managed=true" in the NetworkManager config, the issue was resolved.

Comment: Please feel free to [accept your own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). That'll help others down the line.